# Access Hbase with in awk script

Tags: awk, metadata, hbase

I am able to access hbase via hbase and awk command

```
echo "scan 'abc'" | hbase shell | awk -F"=" '{print$4}'
```

but i am unable to write above command with in awk programming without system call,how can i get `'{print$4}'` within awk script so that i can process the data within the script.

**EDIT**

What i am doing right now is invoking a system call within my.awk and saving it in another file but i want to use the $4 within my.awk ,rather saving it in another file. what i have done is:

```
#!/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
        ftable="echo" " \"" "scan" " " "'abc'" "\" ""| hbase shell | awk -F" "" "= '{print$4}'> abc.txt";
        print ftable;
        system(ftable);
    }
```

i think now it is much more clear,basically i dont want to invoke system call because it always return 0;Even shell will work but what i want is to get this printed output within script.

Comment: awk is not shell. UNIX shell is an environment from which to call tools with a language to sequence those calls. awk is a UNIX tool to parse text files. hbase, I'm guessing, is another UNIX tool with some other purpose. From awk you CAN invoke a shell in a couple of different ways, but it's not clear why you'd want to have shall call awk to call shell to call hbase rather than just having shell call both awk and hbase if both tools are required to solve your problem. If you update your question with an explanation and some sample input/output, we could help.

Comment: There is _typically_ no reason to invoke a shell command from _inside_ an awk program. In your edit you're invoking `awk` from inside `awk`, which is even more - pardon the pun - awkward. It's still unclear whar you're trying to achieve here. As an aside, the `system()` function is meant to just invoke a shell command without capturing its _output_; only its _exit code_ is returned; by contrast, `<shell command> | getline` would allow you to read a command's output - again: this is an advanced technique only used in unusual circumstances.

Comment: @mklement0 thanks i have edited my question and how can i use <shell command> | getline within awk script ,So indirectly you are suggesting to have shell script and to call awk and hbase separately with in that,aaah sorry its  common sense which i forgot because of shell :)

Comment: I'm still unclear on why you want to invoke a shell command from _within_ your `awk` program - can't you just invoke shell commands beforehand and pass the output of interest to `awk` either as _input instead of a file via a pipe (stdin)_ and/or via _awk variables_? E.g.: `awk -v someAwkVar="$someShellVar" '....'`. If you still want to know how to invoke a shell command from inside an `awk` program and capture its output, search `man awk` for `getline` and see http://awk.info/?tip/getline

Comment: Also note that you can selectively redirect to output files inside an `awk` program without involving the shell; e.g.: let's say you're interested in `$4` in your awk program while at the same time saving it to a file whose name you pass as a variable: `awk -v out=abc.txt '{ print $4 > out }' <<<'one two three four five'`

Comment: Show some small, representative sample input and expected output that demonstrates your problem. The script as written doesn't do what you want, so obviously we can't tell from reading what it is you want and the explanation so far isn't helping as you're telling us HOW you want to solve a problem (rather than WHAT the problem is) in a way that doesn't seem to make sense.